# Why *all* $\epsilon > 0$, in the $\varepsilon-\delta$ limit definition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, definition

Definition of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$:

> $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 s.t. |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$
>
> $ if \ 0 < |x-a| < \delta$

**Question**: Why can't we [weaken the assumption](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-%E2%80%93-and-answer-them/) to

> $\exists N > 0$ s.t.
>
> $\forall \epsilon \in (0, N), \exists \delta > 0 s.t. |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$
>
> $ if \ 0 < |x-a| < \delta$

?

I think they are not equivalent. If they are, please explain how the latter proves the former and why we still need to have case 1 below.

---

Consider proving

> $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 s.t. |x^2 - 25| < \epsilon$
>
> $if \ 0 < |x-5| < \delta$

---

**We first try to find some $\delta$.**

$|x^2 - 25|$

$ = |x - 5| |x + 5| < \epsilon$ if we maybe choose $\delta$ s.t. ...:

Let $M > 0$ (further restrictions may be needed).

If $|x-5| < M$, then we have

$$- M < x-5 < M$$

$$\to 5 - M < x < 5 + M$$

$$\to 10 - M < x + 5 < 10 + M$$

$$\to (-10 - M) < 10 - M < x + 5 < 10 + M$$

$$|x + 5| < 10 + M$$

So we might choose $\delta = \min\{M, \frac{\epsilon}{10+M} \}$ for the two cases in the proof (it seems no further restrictions on M are needed).

---

**Proof:** Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Case 1: $$\epsilon > M(10+M)$$

$$\delta = M$$

$$\to |x - 5| |x + 5| < M |x+5| < \frac{\epsilon}{10+M} (10+M) = \epsilon$$

Case 2: $$0 < \epsilon < M(10+M)$$

$$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{10+M}$$

$$\to |x - 5| |x + 5| < \frac{\epsilon}{10+M} (10+M) = \epsilon$$

Case 3: $$\epsilon = M(10+M)$$

Pick either value of $\delta$.

QED

---

**Question in the case of this example**: Cases 1 and 3 refer to tolerance levels $\ge M(10+M)$. Why do we care about those? Why isn't enough that we have proved case 2?

I'm thinking that we could just find $\delta$'s that work for $\epsilon \in (0,N)$ for some $N > 0$. Why do we care about **all** $\epsilon$ ie $\epsilon \ge N$?

Comment: I wouldnt say the two are equivalent.  I'd say they are identical.  They both so for all $\epsilon$ such that $N > \epsilon> 0$.   What I can't figure out is why you think have an utterly unnecessary N helps in any way.

Comment: The equivalence is precisely what justifies formulations often found in proofs such as: "Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We may assume without loss of generality that $\epsilon<\frac12$. ..."

Comment: @fleablood I'm just wondering why anyone cares about cases 1 or 3 in the proof above. We already proved the case for positive numbers up to M(10+M) so to me that should be enough. I think we should be concerned about SMALLER not LARGER tolerance levels

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Cool so I can just show Case 2 then add 'WOLOG' beforehand?

Comment: @fleablood '
1
down vote
accept
Your intuition is pretty good. You actually claimed that it doesn't matter what the function does "far away" from f(x0)f(x0) (More precisely, outside some neighborhood of f(x0)f(x0)).

shareciteeditflag
answered 2 days ago

Elimination'

Comment: Who says we care about all $\epsilon>0$? It is simply easier to write the definition that way! That definition is also clearly equivalent to limiting the choices of $\epsilon$ to some sequence of positive numbers  converging to $0$. Say, $\epsilon=1/n$, or $\epsilon=10^{-n}$ for all naturals $n>0$. IIRC some textbooks do it using such a sequence. But defining it the usual way avoids drawing undue attention to any specific sequence, so it is more elegant.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The title question assumes the two statements are not equivalent, which, as it turns out, they are. Thanks for the info on the sequences

Answer (score 4):

You can "weaken" it that way (it turns out to not be a weakening at all, except in apparence). Even take $N=1$ (or any fixed positive number) if you want.

Clearly, the first definition implies the second. Now, for the converse: assume we have 
$\exists N>0 \text{ s.t. }\forall \varepsilon \in (0, N), \exists \delta > 0 s.t. |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon \ if \ 0 < |x-a| < \delta$.

Then, fix *any* $\varepsilon > 0$, and choose $\varepsilon^\prime = \min(\varepsilon, N/2)$. Then use the above assumption: there exists one $\delta$ for $\varepsilon^\prime$, and this $\delta$ will then also work for $\varepsilon$ as $\varepsilon^\prime \leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: thanks clement c. wait so it is weakened? not equivalent really?

Comment: No, it is equivalent. It **looks** like a weakening, but it turns out to be exactly equivalent -- see the answer, which shows it.

Comment: so the proof is correct if we omit cases 1 and 3?

Comment: To be honest, I have some trouble parsing what you do in the second part of your question. What is this $M$ supposed to be? You are given $\varepsilon$ and aim at finding a $\delta$ -- the introduction of an extra parameter $M$ looks weird, especially given the way it is introduced.

Comment: clement c, it's some positive number. I could try $M=1$ but using $1$ in situations like these doesn't always work like we use it on the same problem except $x \to -5$: $M$ will have to be greater than 10, I think.

Comment: The thing is, here you write "If $\exists M$ such that $\lvert x-5\rvert < M$." This is not very helpful in defining $M$ -- there is *always* such an $M$, depending on $x$: take $M=\lvert x-5\rvert +1$. What you should do is to choose yourself a fixed $M>0$ (e.g., 1 as you say) independent of $x$, and then say "for all $x$ s.t. $\lvert x-5\rvert < M$, we get [...]."

Comment: Is that what I said? I think I said $\exists M > 0$...no difference? Btw, M is a value of delta so of course it doesn't depend on x...?

Comment: Look at the sentence you wrote: $M$ is defined by the statement $\exists M > 0 \text{ s.t. } \lvert x-5\rvert < M$. This, mathematically, means that $M$ is allowed to depend on $x$. I am basically pointing out that the way you wrote the proof (not its spirit, but what is effectively written) is not rigorous: you probably did not write what you meant to write.

Comment: So why don't all delta's depend on x?

Comment: @BCLC $\delta$ can depend on $a$, and $\varepsilon$ (and, I reckon, possibly on $L$) -- not on $x$.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. If M depends on x the way you described, then it seems $\delta$ depends on x in the same way...?

Comment: My point is that $M$ must **not** depend on $x$ the way I pointed in my comment. But what you have written does not preclude it.

Comment: Wait I think I get it now. Reread your comments. I think the for all x is kind of understood? It's like with the original definition. Delta is supposed to be for all x...I think?

Comment: Don't write "$\exists M $ s.t. [...]." Write "Let $M$ be a fixed constant (to be determined later). Then, for any $x$ such that $\lvert x-t\rvert < M$, we have [...]." (and at the very end, give the explicitly value of $M$ you think is best -- e.g., $M=1$)

Comment: Ah thanks ^-^ okay now? If so.....:   so the proof is correct if we omit cases 1 and 3?

Comment: Yes, it would still go through (since $\delta(10+M) \leq \varepsilon$ no matter the value of $\varepsilon$ is).

Comment: Hmmm...really? If we said $M < |x-5| < \frac{\epsilon}{10+M}$ while $\epsilon > M(10+M)$, do we still have $|x+5| < 10+M$?

Comment: You chose $\delta = \min(M,\frac{\varepsilon}{10+M})$. If $\lvert x-5\rvert \leq \delta$, then (in particular) $\lvert x-5\rvert \leq M$; so that $\lvert x+5\rvert \leq 10+M$. You then have $$\lvert x^2-25\rvert \leq \delta (10+M) \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{10+M}\cdot (10+M) = \varepsilon.$$

Comment: I meam, what if delta would just be $\epsilon/(M+10)$ for the sake of focusing on just case 2?

Comment: You **chose** $\delta$ as the minimum of the two quantities -- in the rest of the proof, you can (and should) use that.

Comment: ...what if just that one value of delta for only that one case? That's kind of (or was supposed to be) the main focus of the post...........

Comment: Then you can just say "If $\varepsilon > M(10+M)$, set $\varepsilon^\prime =  M(10+M)$, otherwise $\varepsilon^\prime =  \varepsilon$" and continue as you did, but with $\varepsilon^\prime$ instead of $\varepsilon$. You can now set $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon^\prime}{10+M}$, everything goes through, and at the end you proved $< \varepsilon^\prime$. As $\varepsilon^\prime \leq \varepsilon$, this shows what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

The definitions are equivalent. Assume that there exists $N > 0$ such that for any $\varepsilon \in (0, N)$ there exists $\delta > 0$ for which $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.

We want to show that given $\varepsilon' > 0$ there exists $\delta' > 0$ for which $0 < |x - a| < \delta'$ implies that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon'$. Consider two cases

1. If $\varepsilon' \geq N$, take $\varepsilon = \frac{N}{2}$ and obtain $\delta > 0$ for which $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon = \frac{N}{2} < \varepsilon'$ so taking $\delta' = \delta$ works.
2. If $0 < \varepsilon' < N$, take $\varepsilon = \varepsilon'$ and obtain $\delta > 0$ for which $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon = \varepsilon'$ so taking $\delta' = \delta$ works.

Thus, once you have proven the equivalence, cases $1$ and $3$ become redundant.

Comment: Thanks levap. does this proof that they are equivalent answer 'why we still need to have case 1 below' ? great if it does

Comment: re your edit, aha! so the proof is correct if we omit cases 1 and 3?

Comment: Yeah, I've added a line that makes this explicit.

Comment: @BCLC What the proof means is that to show that the limit exists, we need to find a $\delta$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ and not necessarily all $\varepsilon$ where $N$ is our "smallness" threshold. We have the freedom to find some $N$ for which our proof works, given that $\varepsilon < N$ but we still need to find such $N$.

Comment: levap, I mean in my proof for the problem in the question: is the proof complete if we omit cases 1 and 3?

Comment: @BCLC Well, if you work with the standard definition, then no but if you prove the equivalence and then quote it, then you can omit the rendurant cases.

Comment: ah but then proving the equivalence is pretty much doing the same thing as what's being done in the other cases?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is pretty good. You actually claimed that it doesn't matter what the function does "far away" from $f(x_0)$ (More precisely, outside some neighborhood of $f(x_0)$).

Comment: Oh thanks. Ummm is the claim correct? XD

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Comment: Sooooo why? Thanks Elimination, but your answer seems more to be suitable for a comment. No offense