# Find Delta from the given information?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

From the given information, find delta $\delta \gt 0$, such that, $$0<|x-x_0|<\delta \implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

Given Information:
$$f(x)=x^2  \\  L=4 \\ \epsilon = 1 \\ x_0=2$$

Here's how I did it:
$$x^2-4<1\\(x-2)(x+2)<1$$

And yea I don't know where to go from that point on...

Comment: Factoring is a red herring and you don't want to do it.  You want $|f(x_0\pm \delta) - f(x_0)|\le \epsilon$ so $|\pm4\delta + \delta^2| \le \epsilon$.  Let $\delta = \epsilon/4$ and you are in fine shape.

Comment: oh.  that won't work but .... $\delta < \epsilon/8$ would be fine... overkill but fine.

Comment: You've reduced it to a basic inequality problem: $x^2-4<1$, so what can $x$ be?  Subtract everything to one side before factoring!!!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640586/

Answer (score 1):

You want to have $|x^2-4|<1 \text{ or } -1<x^2-4<1$.

This gives $3<x^2<5$, so you want to have $\sqrt{3}<x<\sqrt{5}$.

Then if $\delta=\min(2-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}-2)=2-\sqrt{3}$,

$0<|x-2|<\delta\implies |x^2-4|<1$

Comment: So what would be the answer here?

Comment: This shows that $\delta=2-\sqrt{3}$ (or any smaller positive number) will work.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that if $x+2$ wasn't present in the inequality we would  be fine. We bound the term $x+2$ by imposing that $|x-2|<1$ so that $|x+2|<5$. Given $\epsilon>0$ choose $\delta=\min(1, \epsilon/5)$. In the specific case of $\epsilon=1$, $\delta=1/5$ will work.